# Order grouped rows before aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions, postgis

I have a postgis table with point geometries.

#### points table:

```
id | uid | date | geom
```

Points with the same `uid` are the same target. I'm trying to `GROUP BY uid` with the [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) to create a complete target LineString.

```
SELECT uid, ST_MakeLine(geom)
FROM points
GROUP BY uid
```

This works, but I want to make sure the points are in the correct order.
I tried doing this by adding an `ORDER BY date` before grouping.

```
SELECT uid, ST_MakeLine(geom)
FROM points
ORDER BY date <-- does not work
GROUP BY uid

ERROR: syntax error at or near "GROUP"
```

Is there a way to order the grouped rows before they are fed into the aggregate function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order rows within groups in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051724/order-rows-within-groups-in-postgresql)

Comment: Please take a look at documentation: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html  They write that you need a subquery with `order by` while using aggregate version of this function. There are examples there how to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause can be placed at the end of the aggregate arguments.

```
SELECT uid, ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY date)
FROM points
GROUP BY uid
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have the data you want ordered in a temp table, and then group externally by uid?

```
 SELECT uid, ST_MakeLine(geom)
 FROM
 (
    SELECT uid, geom
    FROM points
    ORDER BY date
 ) AS temp
 GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: `ST_MakeLine` should not be in the sub-query.